# How to make deepfake video without a fancy PC?

Tags: deep-learning, deepfakes

Is there any way to make [deepfake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepfake) videos without a fancy computer? For example, run the [DeepFaceLab](https://github.com/iperov/DeepFaceLab) on a website so your own computer won't get involved?

Comment: Please explain your usecase. On what videos are you planning to apply deepfake?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are services that provide free environment to run jupyter notebooks for research purposes (with GPU included, which is crucial for neural networks) - such as Google Colaboratory and Kaggle Kernels. Although they limit how long your computation may run (12 and 6 hours accordingly), which adds some difficulties to the process, although I think it is possible to bypass these restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at using [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/amis/) You can spin up an instance with as much processing power as you need and by using their pre-built images it will already be preconfigured with a lot of the packages etc you might need for any kind of ML.

I see you wanted to use DeepFaceLab which I guess requires some kind of GUI so unsure if this is suitable for your requirements but check it out, it seems to be the best way to perform high-processing machine learning without the *fancy computer*